# How do I create a Git repo out of dev and live versions of an existing site on my webserver?

Tags: linux, git

Some info:

- Running Apache 2.2.3 on CentOS 5.6 64bit (dunno if Apache version is relevant here)
- Git is installed
- It's a VPS, so I have all the access I need

I have an existing website (located at **/home/username/public_html/**) and a dev version of the site (at **/home/username/dev/**) both on the same machine.

I work directly on the dev version (actually working local, but using Sublime Text 2's SFTP plugin to automatically upload on save, so for all intents and purposes, I can be considered to be working directly on the files at /home/username/dev/).

What I would like to do is use Git to push changes from dev to live. Currently I am having to keep track of which files are edited and then FTP or copy them over manually. I want to be able to revert changes if something doesn't go right, things like that.

However, I have never used Git (or any kind of version control) before. I've been googling Git tutorials, but everything I have found assumes something different from my actual setup. The main thing is that most tutorials assume brand new projects. I am terrified of messing up my live site by trying to set up a repo for it.

Anyhow, my question: how can I use my existing folders to create a repo where I can push from /home/username/dev/ to /home/username/public_html/ (or pull vise versa)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up following [this tutorial](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) and it does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your live version came from some version of your dev version you could get everything into a git repository with

- make a copy of your live code

  ```
  $ cp -axf /home/username/public_html/ git_repo
  ```
- putting everything in live under git version control

  ```
  $ cd git_repo
  $ git init
  $ git add .
  $ git commit -m 'Initial import from live version'
  ```
- now copy over all files from the dev version and put them on a branch `dev` in git

  ```
  $ rm *
  $ cp /home/username/dev/* .
  $ git checkout -b dev
  $ git add .
  $ git commit -m 'Initial import from dev version'
  ```

After that your live code will be on the `master` branch in the repository and the dev code in branch `dev`.

If when you are done you always put everything from dev to live, you could achieve this in git with merging your `dev` into your `master` branch (which holds your live code) when you are done.

Your live version could be a clone of that repository from the `master` branch, and deploying would be just a

```
$ git pull
```

there.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to write all this up for me. Maybe I am just not following along correctly (my lack of familiarity with git and Linux in general is a problem), but can you tell me how this actually affects the files in either /home/username/dev/ or /home/username/public_html/?

Comment: It doesn't your current setup. After all the above you will have both versions as branches in one git repository in `git_repo` and could switch your workflow to e.g. deploy with `git pull` like I suggested (but only after you cloned that new repository).